# Estimating maximum effect size and Skillings-Mack test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, confidence-interval, repeated-measures, ranking

I'm working with data that fit the Skillings-Mack test: unbalanced incomplete block design. Or Friedman-test-like with missing data.

In case of negative test result I'd like to estimate the maximum effect size that can "hide" in the data.

With Friedman-test I can fairly easily estimate the size of the effect by taking any two groups and bootstrapping a 95% confidence interval on pairwise differences (be it mean, median, or a trimmed mean).

But when the group sizes in the sample follow binomial distribution, even the highest count groups have very small sizes so the bootstrapped confidence intervals are really large, even when the Skillings-Mack test is very significant (p-value < 1e-9).

### Specific example

What I'm trying to measure is if the Hamming weight of one of the variables (one of the primes used in [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem))) has an impact on the measured variable (time to make an RSA signature with that prime). The problem is that the variable (prime numbers) is uniformly random and of specific bit length (like 1024). That means that the expected Hamming weights will follow a binomial distribution with p=0.5 and N=1024.

I can perform about 10 to 30 measurements before lack of independence has an effect, so I have Skillings-Mack blocks that are no larger than 30 measurements. The specific weights that will be in the block are independent and random. That means that for a specific Hamming weights (say 511 and 513) very few blocks will actually include both, and it looks to me like bootstrapping of a single pair seriously underestimates the effect size in the sample (the Skillings-Mack test can report a p-value of 1e-18 and the pairwise differences 95% confidence interval still includes zero and both sign test and Wilcoxon signed-rank test are negative, with p-values >0.01).

#### Example data

The columns are: block #, group #, value

```
0,970,0.0005337646301498127
0,979,0.0005261829939138577
0,984,0.0005276164559925093
0,988,0.0005300207748127341
0,990,0.0005299520131086142
0,992,0.0005293992860486891
0,993,0.0005277706577715356
0,994,0.0005313986423220974
0,998,0.00052656484082397
0,1003,0.0008258189957865168
0,1007,0.0005323697916666667
0,1016,0.00052937734082397
0,1019,0.0005346163974719101
0,1023,0.0005313576779026217
0,1030,0.0005320523174157303
0,1048,0.000527576954588015
0,1049,0.0005264565777153558
1,985,0.0005240335323033708
1,993,0.000523268668071161
1,994,0.0005316678370786517
1,997,0.0005296673103932585
1,998,0.000520533122659176
1,1002,0.0005318992860486891
1,1004,0.0005240914676966292
1,1008,0.000531628043071161
1,1011,0.000526628043071161
1,1020,0.000533732736423221
1,1030,0.0005267082162921348
1,1034,0.0005294736072097378
1,1039,0.00052875
1,1040,0.0005233974133895131
1,1043,0.0005260878979400749
1,1048,0.0005299403089887641
1,1068,0.000529978054775281
2,983,0.00052984609082397
2,990,0.000529355395599251
2,992,0.0005296892556179775
2,995,0.0005255635533707865
2,1002,0.0005317898525280899
2,1008,0.0005282818352059925
2,1011,0.000526889922752809
2,1017,0.0005296430243445693
2,1018,0.0005295145716292135
2,1024,0.0005307326779026217
2,1025,0.0005319030898876404
2,1028,0.000524471558988764
2,1034,0.0005263298806179775
2,1035,0.0005261376404494383
2,1041,0.0005248390683520599
2,1047,0.0005254462195692884
2,1049,0.0005279576310861423
2,1053,0.000526875
2,1090,0.0005284439372659176
3,988,0.0005288228581460674
3,992,0.0005322050561797752
3,998,0.00052851796582397
3,999,0.0005354865987827716
3,1003,0.0005313743562734083
3,1007,0.0005290809339887641
3,1012,0.0005250324789325843
3,1013,0.0005284047284644194
3,1015,0.0005315247542134831
3,1016,0.0005298159527153558
3,1020,0.0005272056413857678
3,1022,0.0005311215472846442
3,1028,0.000527001404494382
3,1030,0.00052484609082397
3,1045,0.0005310185510299625
3,1056,0.0005270110603932584
3,1059,0.0005325514981273408
3,1081,0.0005280811095505618
3,1087,0.0005288600187265918
4,984,0.0005270886001872659
4,987,0.0005309629564606742
4,996,0.0005245880149812734
4,999,0.0005280070809925094
4,1005,0.0005273709620786516
4,1006,0.000527496488764045
4,1008,0.0005227668539325843
4,1017,0.0005292155313670412
4,1023,0.0005251521535580524
4,1026,0.0005266338951310861
4,1028,0.0005204108146067416
4,1032,0.0005281574789325843
4,1033,0.0005295868445692884
4,1034,0.0005297650397940075
4,1044,0.000527808988764045
4,1060,0.0005318574438202248
4,1063,0.0005257876872659176
4,1082,0.0005329073033707865
5,990,0.0005326916549625468
5,1000,0.0005313629447565543
5,1008,0.0005259375
5,1012,0.000528058286516854
5,1014,0.0005283037804307116
5,1019,0.0005263117392322097
5,1020,0.0005293826076779026
5,1021,0.0005300029260299626
5,1023,0.0005244540028089888
5,1025,0.0005263594335205992
5,1027,0.0005236528558052434
5,1029,0.000525546875
5,1035,0.0005264761821161049
5,1047,0.0005253397120786517
5,1061,0.0005254330524344569
5,1085,0.0005278075257490637
6,975,0.000528582338483146
6,984,0.0005293834854868914
6,997,0.0005275029260299626
6,999,0.0005254705056179775
6,1002,0.0005282262406367042
6,1006,0.0005241300912921348
6,1009,0.0005222389981273408
6,1011,0.0005282285814606741
6,1013,0.0005289940308988764
6,1018,0.0005246822331460674
6,1022,0.0005258462078651685
6,1025,0.0005305901802434457
6,1031,0.0005288910346441947
6,1038,0.0005260562968164794
6,1042,0.0005303657537453183
6,1051,0.0005279994733146067
6,1052,0.0005318884597378277
6,1057,0.0005336516853932584
7,992,0.0005308634714419476
7,993,0.0005244461025280899
7,1000,0.0005285498595505618
7,1006,0.0005270891853932585
7,1019,0.0005279953768726591
7,1022,0.0005240010533707865
7,1023,0.0005274054892322098
7,1024,0.000527904377340824
7,1026,0.0005262181062734082
7,1030,0.0005267579588014981
7,1033,0.0005292430360486891
7,1042,0.0005259085323033708
7,1043,0.0005284301849250937
7,1054,0.0005283090472846442
7,1074,0.000528675386235955
7,1076,0.0005269891151685394
```

### Question

How to estimate the effect size for such data?

As far as I understand, repeated measurements ANOVA on ranks could also be used for testing such data, but I've also seen few suggestions against it if the groups have different sizes (and mine very much do). Is that correct? If not, are there ways to estimate effect size with rANOVA on ranks?

I know that in case of negative test, I can just modify measurements in a specific group and run the Skillings-Mack test again and again to see when it becomes significant to know what is the effect it can detect for the data at hand, but that's a rather expensive for the sample sizes I expect to need to collect (hundreds of millions of measurements), not to mention that it's rather hard to rigorously specify which group should be modified.

### Background

Since I'm measuring computation time of operations on a computer, I need to be able to differentiate sub 1 ns effects of operations that take about 1 ms, but I also need to know when the sample is large enough and clean enough to detect effect of specific size.

Comment: @MikeHunter No, I'm not asking for estimation of statistical power. I've added a paragraph to the Question section that would do sort-or what I need.

Comment: @MikeHunter again, you're thinking about statistical power, not effect size estimation. Even if I get confidence interval from ANOVA, it will be a confidence interval *on ranks* I'm interested in the underlying confidence interval, expressed in nanoseconds.

Comment: What do you mean by "create the data matrix to support that more granular analysis."? That's precisely why I need that estimate for, to know how big it needs to be to get 1 ns precision, _given the real noise experienced during data collection_

Comment: Well, I did quite a bit of googling for solutions before writing it here, so yeah... it's not an everyday stats problem, *that* I do know. I've added example data (real data, but only a subset). I do not see a point in implementing an rANOVA on ranks if I can't convert the confidence interval back to raw value represented in fractions of a second. The whole point of ranking is to remove the magnitude of the differences from analysis.

Comment: (I think it's already gone). value is the time to process the data represented in seconds (i.e. first line in the example means that in first group of measurements, the explanatory variable's Hamming weight was 970 and processing took 0.5ms. The values are not temporarily sequential. I'm not deriving many metrics, just Skillings-Mack and estimate of the pairwise differences between few groups (like take all blocks that have groups 1024 and 1023 calculate pairwise differences, report bootstrapped CI of them)

Comment: Sorry, I don't see anything. The subsequent measurements in a specific group aren't independent and identically distributed, just like in Friedman tests. Only the differences between measurements in groups are independent. So summary statistics on a per-group basis are not really meaningful, not when looking for ns differences. I have no problem detecting differences, my problem is knowing when there's no point in more testing.

Comment: Now, I could indeed go for the Bayesian approach, but a). in my experience it's far more CPU intensive than just bootstrapping, and b). in my previous experiments, for multimodal distributions it severely underperformed sign test or Friedman test (like 95% CI still including 0 when the tests had p-values <1e-9). And I don't know stan well enough to actually model multimodal distributions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151638/discussion-between-hubert-kario-and-mike-hunter).

Comment: Which part of it is relevant? As far as I can tell I'm applying all the lessons from it? That's why I'm using Skillings-Mack in the first place...

Comment: Sorry, but effect sizes when testing for [side-channel leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack) are everything. Like I said, if the system is running as required, the null hypothesis that all expected values are equal, does hold to an arbitrary degree.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I went with two approaches, one more data specific, and one more generic.

### Data specific

In my particular example, if there are between group differences, then it's most likely that there is a linear relationship between the Hamming weight (the group ID) and the value.

From that, I can create pairwise differences to estimate the slope of the weight to time relationship: sort the values by group ID within a block, take pairs of values from a specific block, and save the pairwise differences between them. I can then calculate a median, mean, and bootstrapped confidence intervals on such data (or even run a sign test or a Wilcoxon signed-rank test).

Yes, it doesn't take into account the difference between compared groups (basically assumes that it's always 1), but it should be good enough as first order approximation. The upside is that it takes into account more than just pairwise differences between two specific groups, so more data, and that means smaller confidence interval, without needing to worry about independence of data points.

### Generic approach

Since I'm interested specifically about the question "is the sample large enough to detect 1 ns or 0.1 ns deviation", in case of negative result from the Skillings-Mack test I can modify the data: change all the values in a specific group (like 5th most common) and see if the Skillings-Mack test becomes positive then (returns p-value smaller than 1e-9). If yes, then it most likely would have detected a 1 ns deviation.